# Make browser zoom scale effective viewport

Tags: javascript, css, html

What I want to is set `<body>` to be 100% width and height (or viewport width / height), but when the user zooms, either via pinching on mobile or numerous methods on a desktop browser, I want the viewport to scale with the zoom. So where as body used to be the size of the viewport, if you zoom in 2x, I want the viewport to be 2x bigger.

One possible solution would be to measure the viewport in javascript on load and then set body to be those dimensions, then it would scale the way I desire. I could then put more hooks into viewport resizing to get it to appear the correct size, but it'd be nicer if there was a css / html solution, even if it doesn't necessarily work on all browsers.

Comment: you can check vw & vh unit

Comment: @user2181397 Yeah, unfortunately that has the same issue as 100% width. If you zoom, the unit's scale in proportion. A div with 100vw will always be the size of the screen / window independent of zoom. At least, it is on all browsers I interact with.